# Do I have to own an offshore company to benefit from the “Residente não habitual” (NHR) tax exempt in Portugal?

Tags: taxes, portugal, tax-deductions

I have never been to Portugal and would like to live there for some years.

I have heard that for people like me (who's never been to Portugal before), there is a 10-year Tax Exempt for my non-Portugal income. That means no matter how much money I earned during the 10 years, I don't need to pay any tax to Portugal as long as my income is not coming from inside Portugal.

Can the income be transferred to my Portugal bank account directly?

Do I need to register an off-shore company to benefit from this rule?